# DAX finding first date in table where column changes value

Tags: date, powerbi, filtering, dax

I have a table with a date column and a number column.

Example:
| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-'21  | 4 |
| 02-01-'21 | 4 |
| 03-01-'21 | 2 |

I want to add a calculated column that returns the first date where the number is different than the current row.

I've tried using the following formula:

```
Column = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table'[Date].[Date]),
    FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Date].[Date] > EARLIER('Table'[Date].[Date])),
    FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Number] <> EARLIER('Table'[Number]))
)
```

But this only returns the first date after the current date:
| Date | Number | Column |
| ---- | ------ | ------ |
| 01-01-'21  | 4 | 02-01-'21 |
| 02-01-'21 | 4 | 03-01-'21 |
| 03-01-'21 | 2 | 04-01-'21 |

And the result I'm looking for is:

| Date | Number | Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-'21 | 4 | 03-01-'21 |
| 02-01-'21 | 4 | 03-01-'21 |
| 03-01-'21 | 2 | **some date in the future where [Number] changes again** |

Somehow it feels like the second filter is being ignored.

Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The tables don't work, in the example it does:

[image: PS: the tables somehow don't work]

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try below code.

```
Column =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table (5)'[Date].[Date] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table (5)',
        AND (
            'Table (5)'[Date].[Date] > EARLIER ( 'Table (5)'[Date].[Date] ),
            'Table (5)'[Number] <> EARLIER ( 'Table (5)'[Number] )
        )
    )
)
```

It works for me hope it helps you too. Screenshot for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you are putting 2 filters in which only join up the results. Instead you need to have a filter on both conditions like below:

```
Column = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table'[Date].[Date]),
    FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Date].[Date] > EARLIER('Table'[Date].[Date]) && 'Table'[Number] <> EARLIER('Table'[Number]))
)
```

I tested this code and got the following result:

[image]

Exatly what you where looking for

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I get the same result as when I'm using the dax stated above

Comment: Well, I tested my proposed code and it is doing what you are looking for..